# Why does the DisplayLinkManager perform so many I/O write operations?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, displaylink

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with 4 monitors connected with [DisplayLink DVI > USB](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters) adapters. I noticed that the DisplayLinkManager process performs many I/O write operations, as the screenshot below illustrates (over 60 GB if I/O writes for 8 hours of uptime).

Is it typical, and what explains it? Does DisplayLinkManager write on disk all the visual information that need to be displayed on the monitors connected with DisplayLink DVI > USB adapters?

[image]